# Flutter_reactive_ble connection stream not updating connection state

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, riverpod, riverpod-generator

I am having problem using the flutter_reactive_ble package and Riverpod generator.

I am able to scan for devices, but when I select the device I want to connect to the
first time I attempted to connect I only get this out put in the consol.

flutter: Device not connected
flutter: Start connecting to 3d19f04a-1e9e-1406-68de-2b6085bf185c

if I try again the second time I get this:

flutter: Device not connected
flutter: Start connecting to 3d19f04a-1e9e-1406-68de-2b6085bf185c
flutter: ConnectionState for device 3d19f...f185c : DeviceConnectionState.connecting
flutter: device connecting

And then nothing else, I never get updated that it is connected.

My View Widget build method that calls for the connection is this

```
@override
  Widget build(context, ref) {
    final bleStateUpdate = ref.watch(bleStatusMonitorProvider);
    final connectionStateUpdate = ref.watch(bleDeviceConnectorProvider);
    final connectionState = connectionStateUpdate.connectionState ??
        DeviceConnectionState.disconnected;

    if (bleStateUpdate == BleStatus.ready) {
      switch (connectionState) {
        case DeviceConnectionState.connected:
          debugPrint('device connected');
          break;
        case DeviceConnectionState.disconnected:
          debugPrint('Device not connected');
          ref
              .read(bleDeviceConnectorProvider.notifier)
              .connect(ref.read(notioDeviceProvider)!.id.toString());
          break;
        case DeviceConnectionState.connecting:
          debugPrint('device connecting');
          break;
        case DeviceConnectionState.disconnecting:
          debugPrint('device disconnecting');
          break;
        default:
          debugPrint('unknown connection state');
      }
    }

    ....
```

this is my Provider

```
.... Imports ... 

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class BleDeviceConnector extends _$BleDeviceConnector {
  final FlutterReactiveBle _ble = locator.get<FlutterReactiveBle>();
  StreamSubscription<ConnectionStateUpdate>? _connectionStreamSub;
  final Duration _connectionTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 10);

  @override
  ConnectionStateUpdate build() {
    return const ConnectionStateUpdate(
        deviceId: "",
        connectionState: DeviceConnectionState.disconnected,
        failure: null);
  }

  Future<void> connect(String deviceId) async {
    debugPrint('Start connecting to $deviceId');
    _connectionStreamSub = _ble
        .connectToDevice(id: deviceId, connectionTimeout: _connectionTimeout)
        .listen(
          handleConnectionState,
          onError: (Object e) =>
              debugPrint('Connecting to device $deviceId resulted in error $e'),
        );
  }

  Future<void> disconnect(String deviceId) async {
    try {
      debugPrint('disconnecting to device: $deviceId');
      await _connectionStreamSub?.cancel();
    } on Exception catch (e, _) {
      debugPrint("Error disconnecting from a device: $e");
    } finally {
      state = ConnectionStateUpdate(
        deviceId: deviceId,
        connectionState: DeviceConnectionState.disconnected,
        failure: null,
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> handleConnectionState(ConnectionStateUpdate event) async {
    debugPrint(
        'ConnectionState for device ${event.deviceId} : ${event.connectionState}');
    state = event;
  }

  Future<void> dispose() async {
    await _connectionStreamSub?.cancel();
  }
}
```

I am not certain if this a Flutter_reactive_ble problem or if it is the way I am using the bleDeviceConnectorProvider.